# When using dynamic cast to do upcast, it is a kind of run-time or compile-time process?

Tags: c++, casting, runtime, compile-time, dynamic-cast

I'm currently trying to figure out the performance of `dynamic cast`.

I know `dynamic cast` need inheritance relationship between two classes and need virtual function(need RTTI).

So it means I know use `dynamic cast` to do downcast is a run-time process because need to check RTTI info.

So what about upcast? It has same function with `static cast`. But I want to know if use `dynamic cast` to do some upcast, it will be a run-time process or compile-time process?

Comment: If the relation is known at compile time, the cast will use that. Otherwise it has to be a runtime check.

Comment: So if the relation is valid, so the upcast will be a kind of compile-time?